# How to validate token provided by MSAL in C#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, msal

I am creating an Angular app which is using MSAL to authenticate user via Microsoft account credentials. Just like we use Google authentication). The MSAL returns user's Azure id and other details.

Now, I am planning to pass the same Azure id to the Web API (ASP.NET Core C#). The web API should validate the same id. However, I am unable to find any library/code sample for the validation. Can it be done using Microsoft Graph?

Please let me know.

Tried online search but didn't help.